# How to Hide Splash screen once the App is loaded in react native using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native

I have splash screen in my app and after 5 seconds it will navigate to another screen .

What i want is splash screen should be shown only the first time when the app is loaded and once user comes out of the app and open it agian then it should not show splash screen.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, BackHandler, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import colors from '../styles/colors';

class SplashScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // Start counting when the page is loaded
        this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
            Actions.welcome()
        }, 5000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('../assets/BSWH-splash.jpg')}
                    style={styles.backgroundImage}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    backgroundImage: {
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        flex: 1,
    },
    logoText: {
        fontSize: 34,
        color: colors.white,
        margin: 10,
    },
});
export default SplashScreen;
```

I have used react-native-router-flux for navigation

please help me how to hide splash screen once the app is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around that you using. Try to use a npm package to have a perfect result and the best npm package out there is [crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

There you can hide the SplashScreen in componentDidMount method with `Splashscreen.hide()` function.

But if you still want to go with this method then you can try

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout( () => {this.load()}, 2500);       
    }
    load = () => {
      Actions.StartOrder()   //Go to StartOrder screen in 2500ms or 2.5secs
    }
```

Here, setTimeout() method of JS will help you to redirect to a particular screen in the interval you mention !!